# Start Node Js Server Automatically on Pc Start Up

Tags: windows, boot, node.js, cmd.exe

I have a Node Server.

And I want that my Node Server starts automatically when my Pc Starts.

Right Now I am doing this Manually.

Like this:

1. First I open Command Prompt.
2. Then I Type

   ```
   cd node
   ```
3. Then I type

   ```
   node server.js
   ```

I want these 3 Steps to perform automatically when my Pc starts.

Any solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

Write your Script to a .bat file `C:\node server.js` and place in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\` The script will run when you login.